# neo4j REST API getting HTML response instead of JSON

Tags: api, rest, neo4j

I'm trying to use neo4j's REST API from an Apache Flex front-end.  When my Flex app connects to the base URL (`http://localhost:7474/db/data/`) to discover other service URLs, it gets replies back in HTML rather than JSON format (just like if I enter the base URL into my browser).

In the Flex HTTP request, I've set the *Content-Type* and *Accept* headers both to "application/json" but it hasn't made a difference.  I've also tried both *GET* and *POST* request methods.

I've verified neo4j is capable of sending JSON responses through a simple telnet window, so it must be "intelligently" formatting the reply based on something in the HTTP request.  I'd thought the *Content-Type* and *Accept* headers would take care of it, though.

I realize the problem isn't technically in neo4j, but rather somewhere inside Flex's HTTPService (and supporting) classes, but I've been unsuccessful in working around the apparent bug/limitation.

Is there a way to simply force all such responses from neo4j to just be in JSON format?

Thanks,

Chris

*** EDIT ***

As requested below, here is the exact reply I'm getting in my Flex app:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html><head><title>Root</title><meta content="text/html; charset=utf-8" http-equiv="Content-Type">
<link href='http://resthtml.neo4j.org/style/rest.css' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
<script type='text/javascript' src='/webadmin/htmlbrowse.js'></script>
</head>
<body onload='javascript:neo4jHtmlBrowse.start();' id='root'>
<div id='content'><div id='header'><h1><a title='Neo4j REST interface' href='/'><span>Neo4j REST interface</span></a></h1></div>
<div id='page-body'>
<table class="root"><caption>Root</caption>
<tr class='odd'><th>relationship_index</th><td><a href="http://localhost:7474/db/data/index/relationship">http://localhost:7474/db/data/index/relationship</a></td></tr>
<tr><th>node_index</th><td><a href="http://localhost:7474/db/data/index/node">http://localhost:7474/db/data/index/node</a></td></tr>
</table>
<div class='break'>&nbsp;</div></div></div></body></html>
```

This is the same result I get if I just put the base URL in my web browser manually and retrieve it that way.

Comment: So perhaps tag this post with "flex", "http", "json" too? It works fine with javascript and node.js and afaik it only looks at the http-headers, are you sure they arrive at the server? Perhaps use ngrep or tcpdump to check?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out.  When I compiled and ran my Flex app as a browser-based app, it used the browser's native capability to request the URL, blowing away my customized Content-Type and Accept headers.

When I compiled and ran as an Adobe Air desktop app, it worked fine and I received the proper JSON response.

Likely this is a bug in Flash Player, as the documentation for the Flex HTTPService class doesn't give any limitation on changing Content-Type or other headers when running in a browser vs. Air.

-Chris

Comment: Thank you, I had this problem too, using the Jersey API. Adding resource.accept(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON) did the trick.